# How Can I Define Variable And Use it Overall the View specially inside For loops in MVC5?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, for-loop, global-variables

I was researched everywhere that how can I use the Primary Key which is the item's value on my Index View on my project and I didn't found anything about that, I need to use item.Seq_emp outside this for loop (another for loop inside the Index) I'll explain that below

This is my Index view and This my first Table (EmployeeTable)

```
<table id="EmpTable" class="table table-bordered" style="text-align:center;">
    <thead>
    <tr style="background-color: #55a99e;text-align:center">

            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Emp_Code)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Name)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Birth)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Hiring_Date)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Strating_Date)
            </th>

        </tr>


    </thead>


    @foreach (var item in Model.Employees)
    {

        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Emp_Code)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Birth)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Hiring_Date)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Strating_Date)
                </td>


           <td>
                @foreach (var item2 in Model.Attchment)
                 {

                if (item2.Attach != null)
                 {
         if (item2.Seq_Emp == item.Seq_Emp)
          {
        string imageBase64 Convert.ToBase64String(item10.Attach);
      string imageSrc = string.Format("data:image/gif;base64{0}", imageBase64);
      <img src="@imageSrc" width="100" height="100" class="thumbnail" />
          }
                  }
                 }
           </td>
            </tr>

        </tbody>
```

and my problem is that when I want to equalize the value of the new item (item3) outside this for loop with the value of the item it's given me the error that (the name item doesn't exist in the current context) how can I solve that, please?!

is that mean I should define more than variable inside the for loop?? if that possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can declare local variables in razor. Below is one example

```
@{
    string someString = ""; //You can set this to whatever in your for loop once you find variable you want. You can also set this to whatever from Model too
}
```